# C# Using LINQ to select max ID of row

Tags: c#, linq

I have a breadcrumb table and I want to return the row that was most recently inserted. In SQL it would be a `MAX()` function but not sure how to do the equivalent in LINQ. Basically I want to select the row that has the highest `BreadCrumbID WHERE ProjectID = 49`.

Here's the query I have right now that would select all rows `WHERE ProjectID = 49`. I want to select the row that has the highest `BreadCrumbID`.

Thanks!

Code:

```
using (dbPSREntities5 myEntities = new dbPSREntities5())
{
   var currentStatus = (from tbBreadCrumb in myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs.Where(x => x.ProjectID == 49)
                        select new
                        {
                           Status = tbBreadCrumb.BreadCrumbID,
                        });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
using (dbPSREntities5 myEntities = new dbPSREntities5())
    {
        var currentStatus = (from tbBreadCrumb in myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs.Where(x => x.ProjectID == myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs.Max(b=>b.ProjectId))
                              select new
                              {
                                  Status = tbBreadCrumb.BreadCrumbID,
                              });

    }
```

Comment: It seems like this is close... what am I missing? from tbBreadCrumb in myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs.Where(x => x.ProjectID == tbProject.ProjectID).Max(x => x.BreadCrumbID);

Answer (score 3):

Try the following query

```
var currentStatus = 
  from x in myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs
  where x.ProjectID == 49
  orderby x.BreadCrumbID desc
  select x.BreadCrumbID;
```

The first result in that query will be the highest `BreadCrumbID` value where `ProjectID` is 49

Comment: +1: Note that this solution will work even if there are no records that match `ProjectID == 49`.  The solutions using `Max` will fail when no records are returned.

Comment: Is there a way to have LINQ write code that directs the DB to return the max value? That is, is there a way to write a LINQ that translates into something like the equivalent of this T-SQL command: `select max(BreadCrumbID) from [tbBreadCrumbID] where ProjectID = 49'? Here the result is one value, the highest BreadCrumbID. That seems faster than receiving all the BreadCrumbIDs (even if the DB did the sorting, as your query expects). (PS: I've been using the same strategy you're using to get max value results. Still looking for a LINQ that generates the above T-SQL)

Answer (score 2):

This query should get you the highest BreadCrumbId where ProjectID = 4

```
using (dbPSREntities5 myEntities = new dbPSREntities5())
{
    var highestId = myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs.Where(x => x.ProjectID == 49)
                                            .Max(x => x.BreadCrumbID);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Max()` linq extension method

```
var crum = myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs.Max(d=>d.breadcrumbId)
```

Comment: Note that `Max` will throw an exception if `tbBreadCrumbs` has no objects (rows).

Answer (score 1):

Var highestId = myEntities.breadcrumbs.lastOrDefault(x=>x.ProjectId== 49)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It will give 0 if there is no BreadCrumb in ProjectID=49 or give max BreadCrumbID

```
using (dbPSREntities5 myEntities = new dbPSREntities5())
{
    var query=myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs.Where(x => x.ProjectID == 49);
    var highestId = query.Any() ? query.Max(x => x.BreadCrumbID) : 0;
}
```