# getting the MAX() value using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to select the max value of BreadCrumbID from the table tbBreadCrumb when I return multiple rows. Right now I join the tabel tbBreadCrumb to the table tbProjects. If there are multiple entries in tbBreadCrumb I return the multiple entries. But I only want to select the row in tbBreadCrumb that has the highest BreadCrumbID.

Here's my code:

```
using (dbPSREntities5 myEntities = new dbPSREntities5())
    {
        var allDepartments = (from tbProject in myEntities.tbProjects
                              from tbBreadCrumb in myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs.Where(x => x.ProjectID == tbProject.ProjectID) <--- I want to put some sort of Max() function here where it will only slect the row with the max BreadCrumID in the table tbBreadCrumb
                              from refBreadCrumb in myEntities.refBreadCrumbs.Where(x => x.refBreadCrumbID == tbBreadCrumb.StatusID)
                              // select new anon type
                              select new
                              {
                                  ProjectID = tbProject.ProjectID,
                                  Status = refBreadCrumb.BreadCrumbValue,
                                  DateSubmitted = tbBreadCrumb.CreateDateTime,
                                  refDepartmentID = tbProject.refDepartmentID,
                                  ProjectContactFullName = tbProject.ProjectContactFirstName + " " + tbProject.ProjectContactLastName,
                                  ProjectWorkType = tbProject.ProjectWorkType,
                              });

        projectsListView.DataSource = allDepartments;
        projectsListView.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Didn't you ask this before ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212004/c-sharp-using-linq-to-select-max-id-of-row

Comment: yep - tried to simplify the code in the first one and ended up messing everything up and couldn't get any answer to work. Sorry about that.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders: from the link I don't understand that the consensus is on generally removing tags. It's a fine line to walk if you leave it there or not. I for one favour them if they clarify the title.

Comment: @MikeLischke in this case, adding "C#" to the title defaced a decent title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,first get the Maximum `BreadCrumbID` Id.Then use it with `where` in the second query :

```
var breadId = myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs.Max(x => x.BreadCrumbID);
var allDepartments = (from tbProject in myEntities.tbProjects
                          from tbBreadCrumb in myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs.Where(x => x.ProjectID == tbProject.ProjectID && x.BreadCrumbID == breadId)
                          from refBreadCrumb in myEntities.refBreadCrumbs.Where(x => x.refBreadCrumbID == tbBreadCrumb.StatusID)
                          // select new anon type
                          select new
                          {
                              ProjectID = tbProject.ProjectID,
                              Status = refBreadCrumb.BreadCrumbValue,
                              DateSubmitted = tbBreadCrumb.CreateDateTime,
                              refDepartmentID = tbProject.refDepartmentID,
                              ProjectContactFullName = tbProject.ProjectContactFirstName + " " + tbProject.ProjectContactLastName,
                              ProjectWorkType = tbProject.ProjectWorkType,
                          });
```

Update:

```
var allDepartments = (from tbProject in myEntities.tbProjects
                          from tbBreadCrumb in myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs.Where(x => x.ProjectID == tbProject.ProjectID && x.BreadCrumbID == myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs.Where(y => y.ProjectID == tbProject.ProjectID).Max(y => y.BreadCrumbID))
                          from refBreadCrumb in myEntities.refBreadCrumbs.Where(x => x.refBreadCrumbID == tbBreadCrumb.StatusID)
                          // select new anon type
                          select new
                          {
                              ProjectID = tbProject.ProjectID,
                              Status = refBreadCrumb.BreadCrumbValue,
                              DateSubmitted = tbBreadCrumb.CreateDateTime,
                              refDepartmentID = tbProject.refDepartmentID,
                              ProjectContactFullName = tbProject.ProjectContactFirstName + " " + tbProject.ProjectContactLastName,
                              ProjectWorkType = tbProject.ProjectWorkType,
                          });
```

Comment: I see how this would work, but the problem here is that there's a different max BreadCrumbID for each ProjectID. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user1431633 I understand what you are asking now,I will update my question

Comment: I see this and think it should work, but get the error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 FindMaxId(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Yeah I guessed that error.anyway the other way is write that query inside of your query.But it would be really mess :) I have updated my question try again

Comment: First off, thanks for the help. When I add the code I get a red underline with the error: Delegate 'System.Func<dbPSRModel.BreadCrumb,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments.

Comment: It shouldn't give you that error :/ anyway maybe that is because I use x here, `Max(x => x.BreadCrumbID)` try this: `Max(y => y.BreadCrumbID)`